# Using config.ini for a project

Tags: php, security, ini

I'm working on a project with PHP. I was planing to use a file called config.ini for gathering some settings including database information (password, username, name etc..).

I thought about **.htaccess code** to secure config.ini file

```
<Files config.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

My question is if this will provide enough protection for config.ini file. In the end, I wouldn't like any user / visitor to see config.ini or access file if they don't have FTP account access.

Maybe this is a bad approach, I will be glad if you can share your experiences. I would like to go with ini file, maybe changing some settings in server might help to secure it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally recommend keeping the whole configuration file outside your http root, if possible. I think your setting should be enough to block access to it, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend. Riccardo pointed out 1 more important security subject "file / folder permissions" so that's why I would like to accept his answer. Voted your answer up. I accepted your question since you replied my main question if .htaccess protection was enough or not.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be in your DocumentRoot at all, that's the best thing you can do.
Also, set his permissions so that it can be read only by permitted users on the server.

Comment: Voted your answer up Riccardo. Thank you once again. My main question was if .htaccess rule was enough for protecting a file. Kaivosukeltaja replied to my main question as well but you pointed out one more important subject "file / folder permissions". Once again thank you.